# How to reset Image when Bootstrap Modal is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On Click of the Edit Button , i am opening a Modal Dialog associated with that row .
I am facing a issue which is 
The previous Image is not getting reset .

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. On First Row , Click on the Edit Button (Blue Button)
2. A Modal dialog gets opened , change the Image by clicking on Select Image .
3. Now click on the Close Button .
4. Finally click on the Second Row Blue Buton , you will see that Wrong Image gets opened .

https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1556/

This is my code

```
$('#addEquip').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
        var equipmentname = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-equipmentname');
        var equipmentid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-equipmentid');
        var equipimg = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-equipimg');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="equipname"]').val(equipmentname);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="equipid"]').val(equipmentid);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="equipimgtodelete"]').val(equipimg);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="equipimg"]').val("");
        $("#equipmentpicimg").attr('src', equipimg);
});

$('#addEquip').on('hide.bs.modal', function()
{
$('#equipinsertform').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
});
```

Comment: opening the correct image !

Comment: seems to open the correct image for me... if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the form after your modal window has been closed by adding this inside Modal Event of hide :

```
$(this).find('form')[0].reset();
```

Also i prefer using `hidden.bs.modal` instead of `hide.bs.modal`

<sup>**hide.bs.modal:** Occurs when the modal is about to be hidden.</sup>

<sup>**hidden.bs.modal:** Occurs when the modal is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)</sup>

Something like this:

```
$('#addEquip').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/ny04p46d/)